# Change the appearance of a info window on google maps using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function, first I create the marker, then I create an infowindow loading the html from a template, until here everything works perfectly. And here is the problem, I am trying to change the appearance of the infowindow, I am trying for example to hide everything `$(".instagram-marker-infowindow").hide()` just to see if it works, but it doesn't

```
this.addToMap = function(InstaPic){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: { lat: InstaPic.latitude, lng: InstaPic.longtitude },
        map: mymap,
        title: 'Hello World!',
        optimized:false
    });

    $.get("instagram-marker-template.html", function(data){
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: data
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(mymap,marker);
        });
        $(".instagram-marker-infowindow").hide();
    });
}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't?

Comment: the ´$(".instagram-marker-infowindow").hide();´doesnt do anything

Comment: Still I'm unclear about the question, have you checked that the `$.get` gets executed? and since you have bounded the infowindow to the click event, how that supposed to be hidden without opening - doesn't make sense right?